# Vulnerabilidades al instalar un repositorio Node js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm, svelte

Hace un año instalé el siguiente repositorio con éxito:

https://github.com/brandonxiang/svelte-webpack-mpa

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

Y todo funcionaba correctamente.

Hoy lo he vuelto a instalar, y npm devolvió 11 vulnerabilidades, y al ejecutar run dev no funcionó y fue lanzado el siguiente mensaje:

```
npm run dev      

> svelte-webpack-template@1.0.0 dev
> webpack serve --content-base public

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:9000/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from public
Webpack Bundle Analyzer saved report to C:\Users\Documents\development\svelte\svelte-webpack-multipage-base\dist\report.html
‼ ｢wdm｣: assets by path public/static/ 5.24 KiB
  asset public/static/favicon.png 3.05 KiB [emitted] [from: public/static/favicon.png] [copied]  asset public/static/logo-mask.svg 1.37 KiB [emitted] [from: public/static/logo-mask.svg] [copied]
  asset public/static/global.css 835 bytes [emitted] [from: public/static/global.css] [copied] 
asset public/js/index.b07adc4ff3d38bbcf4e7.js 269 KiB [emitted] [immutable] (name: index) 1 related asset
asset index.html 350 bytes [emitted]
runtime modules 30 KiB 14 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 170 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/ 8.36 KiB 23 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/svelte-hmr/runtime/*.js 41.8 KiB 6 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack/hot/*.js 4.4 KiB 4 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/svelte/ 73.3 KiB
    ./node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs 73.1 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/svelte/index.mjs 227 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/svelte-loader/lib/hot-api.js 3.58 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/events/events.js 14.1 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js 24.2 KiB [built] [code generated]
modules by path ./src/pages/index/ 6.71 KiB
  ./src/pages/index/main.js 151 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./src/pages/index/App.svelte 6.56 KiB [built] [code generated]

WARNING in ./node_modules/svelte-hmr/runtime/hot-api.js 131:49-73
export 'default' (imported as '_regeneratorRuntime') was not found in '@babel/runtime/regenerator' (possible exports: __esModule)
 @ ./node_modules/svelte-hmr/runtime/index.js 1:0-44 1:0-44
 @ ./node_modules/svelte-loader/lib/hot-api.js 8:0-50 65:22-34
 @ ./src/pages/index/App.svelte 154:0-157 159:8-38
 @ ./src/pages/index/main.js 1:0-31 2:14-17

WARNING in ./node_modules/svelte-hmr/runtime/hot-api.js 134:15-39
export 'default' (imported as '_regeneratorRuntime') was not found in '@babel/runtime/regenerator' (possible exports: __esModule)
 @ ./node_modules/svelte-hmr/runtime/index.js 1:0-44 1:0-44
 @ ./node_modules/svelte-loader/lib/hot-api.js 8:0-50 65:22-34
 @ ./src/pages/index/App.svelte 154:0-157 159:8-38
 @ ./src/pages/index/main.js 1:0-31 2:14-17

webpack 5.68.0 compiled with 2 warnings in 3640 ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
```

Aun es peor si fijo las vulnerabilidades ejecutando:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

No estoy seguro de por qué ocurre esto.
Es debido a que tengo una nueva versión de Node.js instalada en mi sistema Windows?

Agradezco alguna pista.

Comment: Hmmmm, me temo que lo mejor es actualizar por completo la versión de tu paquete o framework que estas usando (si estas usando uno), ya que normalmente cuando haces `npm audit fix --force`, si que te arregla las vulnerabilidades, pero te daña el proyecto, en el sentido de que muchas veces y como te dicen algunos frameworks, esa acción esta ligada a `breaking changes`, `cambios dañinos`, por suerte lo que te daña solo son normalmente los paquetes y no el proyecto en si, ya que los frameworks terminan funcionando mal al ejecutar `npm audit fix --force`, mas que todo cuando ejecutas con

Comment: El parametro `--force` , ya que si ejecutas `npm audit fix` sin el `--force` npm solo te arreglara los problemas que puede solucionar sin estar sujeto a `breaking changes`, es decir, sin dañarte los paquetes del proyecto, yo normalmente por esto mismo no recomiendo usar `--force` para arreglar vulnerabilidades, puesto que arreglas la seguridad pero destruyes el aplicativo.

Comment: Asi que o una de tres, o actualizas todo a lo maximo que puedas, o cambias de framework o version de framework y migras el proyecto entero, o simplemente ignoras las vulnerabilidades presentadas. Lo recomendable es siempre usar paquetes o frameworks que son activamente usados, reconocidos y que sabes que duraran un buen tiempo en el mercado.

Comment: Otra opcion es solo cambiar los paquetes que te dan problemas de seguridad por otros que hagan lo mismo

Comment: Gracias Riven. Al margen del fix, por qué razón un repositorio que funcionaba perfectamente, ahora al instalar no funciona? Supuestamente son las mismas versiones en el package.json.  Me pregunto si es debido al ^ que tienen delante las versiones de cada repositorio, lo que hace que instale una versión superior.

Comment: Eso es porque conforme transcurre el tiempo, en su momento no se habian descubierto esas vulnerabilidades, pero mientras mas va pasando el tiempo se van descubriendo vulnerabilidades, y quizas en su momento no te mostraba ninguna vulnerabilidad porque no se habian descubierto, pero al lanzarse nuevas versiones se corrigen esos problemas de seguridad detectados.

Comment: Por esto detesto Node

Comment: Al contrario, creo que seria peor que nodejs no te mostrara nada y simplemente dejaras el proyecto tal cual, nodeJS sigue siendo una muy buena herramienta, la culpa realmente no es de nodeJS si no de los repositorios que crea la gente. Aunque de todas maneras eso no es solo de node, las vulnerabilidades y problemas de ese estilo son encontrados a diario en cualquier parte, eso es por parte de cualquier software